# One-parameter distribution used in survival analysis

Tags: statistics

**Background:** I need to project the stock of wood stoves, since these are a major source of air pollution. It turns out that particle emission from a new wood stove is significantly lower than from an old stove. Hence it is necessary to consider when the old stoves will be scraped and replaced. This consideration should be based on a stringent survival analysis framework. However the method needs to be very tractable (Excel) and calibration should be dead simple.

Data is limited; I more or less know the number of wood stoves installed each year. And I assume (as my pre-successor has) that the mean survival time is 30 years.

Furthermore I need to assume a distribution of events. Given that the data at hand is meager I have a strong preference for one-parameter distributions, such as the exponential distribution and the Rayleigh distribution. It seems highly unlikely that a completely new stove is scraped – this rules out the exponential distribution. However I do not believe that the likelihood of scrapping a stove that is 30 years of age is three times larger than the likelihood of scrapping a stove 90 years of age; I would expect the likelihood to be more or less the same, which rules out the Rayleigh distribution.

In order to overcome the problems described above I have cooked up a distribution of events (also known as *event density*):

$$
f(t)=\frac{t}{\sigma^2}*exp(-\frac{t}{\sigma})
$$

Where $\sigma$ controls the scale. It can be shown that the mean survival time is given by $2\sigma$, which allows for untroublesome calibration.

Moreover the distribution of events above leads to the following survival function:

$$
S(t)=exp(-\frac{t}{\sigma})(\frac{t}{\sigma}+1)
$$
Note that this function converges towards the survival function of the exponential distribution.

Furthermore the hazard function is given by

$$
\Lambda(t)=\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}=\frac{\frac{t}{\sigma}}{t+1}
$$

To me these functions seem to be a reasonable conjecture. Given the simplicity of the functions I suspect that I am not the first person to come up with this idea.

**Question:**
Has anyone encountered the distribution function (event density) described above? If so please point me to the source. Does it have a name?

Comment: The gamma distribution.

Comment: Yes, this is a $\gamma(2,1/\sigma)$.

Comment: Indeed it is. Thank you for the quick answers. P.S: Note that I got a slight mistake in the hazard function - exchange the "1" in the denominator with $\sigma$.